# Google Analytics: is it possible to see source of people who click the Like button on a website?

Tags: google-analytics, like

Is it possible to see what source people who clicked the Like button on my website came from??

(It would also be useful to know who they are, but looking through previous posts here, as far as I gather, it seems it's not possible to see who Liked a webpage; though installing the Fb Like button option that has faces of people who Liked the page, might come some way to doing this...)

Comment: Sorry, yes, I meant 'source'. I've edited the q accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

You can measure social engagement in Google Analytics, but whether you can derive their 'source' is a different question (you'd probably have to create a funnel or filter).

Google has the details of implementing social tracking [here](http://code.google.com/apis/analytics/docs/tracking/gaTrackingSocial.html#facebook), and more information on the social plug-in [here](http://www.google.com/support/analyticshelp/bin/answer.py?answer=1316556&topic=1316551).